# Best way to distribute Flutter application Android & iOS. Best Practices in Flutter Beta Distribution

Tags: testing, flutter, distribution, beta-testing

How can I distribute my Flutter app (both Android & iOS) Beta build. I was going through with Crashlytics Beta Distribution. But I think there is some problem distributing Android & iOS app with same name or ids.

Comment: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android 
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-deployment-workflow-done-right-9c2b87ebfd20

Comment: This is a very good article but this doesn't fulfill my requirements. I want Beta release environment and its setup for both Android & iOS.

Comment: Did you try the https://codemagic.io/start/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, there is no need to submit a different build to either of them. The only thing you need to make sure is if there is a already a build in production mode, the build you are currently submitting must have higher version code than existing.

For Android, you have many options,

> Internal test: Quickly distribute your app for internal testing and
>   quality assurance checks.
>
> Closed: Create a closed release to test pre-release versions of your
>   app with a larger set of testers. Once you've tested with a smaller
>   group of employees or trusted users, you can expand your test to an
>   open release. On your App releases page, an Alpha track will be
>   available as your initial closed test. If needed, you can also create
>   and name additional closed tracks.
>
> If you're testing an existing app that you've published before, only
>   users in your test group will receive an update for your closed
>   version.
>
> Open: Create an open release to run a test with a large group and
>   surface your app's test version on Google Play. If you run an open
>   test, anyone can join your testing program and submit private feedback
>   to you. Before choosing this option, make sure your app and store
>   listing is ready to be visible on Google Play.

More information [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

---

For iOS, you have

> Internal Testers
>
> Add up to 25 members of your team who have been assigned the Admin,
>   Technical, App Manager, Developer, or Marketer role to test your app.
>   Each member can test on up to 30 devices. Internal testers can access
>   all of your beta builds available for testing.
>
> External Testers and Groups
>
> Invite up to 10,000 external testers using their email address or by
>   enabling and sharing a public link, which creates an open invitation
>   for anyone to test your app. Simply create a group of testers and add
>   the builds you’d like them to test. You can also create multiple
>   groups and add different builds to each one, depending on which
>   features you want them to focus on. When you add the first build of
>   your app to a group, the build gets sent to beta app review to make
>   sure it follows the App Store Review Guidelines. This is the only beta
>   version of your app that requires a full review, and testing can begin
>   once it’s approved.

More information on TestFlight Beta distribution [here](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) and [here](https://testflight.apple.com/)

More information on Crashlytics beta distribution is [here](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/beta/overview.html). **We can upload iOS & Android builds with same application ids**.

I used Fastlane to make this possible in the best manner. Please check below.

For iOS Deployment: [Beta Distribution](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/beta-deployment/) & [AppStore Distribution](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/)

For Android Deployment: [Beta Distribution](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/beta-deployment/) & [PlayStore Distribution](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/android/release-deployment/)

Comment: Thanks, @CopsOnRoad, This was helpful. I make this done using Fastlane & Crashlytics. I've added a few more things to your answer, now it's complete.